# Invalid Session ID exception on headless chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I execute this statement second time, I get invalid session id exception.
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nav-link")

This is the detail of error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/marchon.py", line 49, in 
element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nav-link")
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws x86_64)

My full code:

```
with open('filename.csv') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvDataFile)
    with my_file:
        headers = ['sku','brand','name','clrcode','color','barcode','size','present','availability','available_by']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(my_file, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        brand_name = ''
        for row in csvReader:
            sku_name = row['sku']
            brand_name = row['brand']
            name = row['name']
            color_code = row['clrcode']
            colour = row['color']
            barcode = row['barcode']
            size = row['size']
            present = row['present']
            availability = row['availability']
            available_by = row['available_by']
            brand_name = brand_name.upper()
            if(var != 0):
                element = browser.find_element_by_class_name("nav-link")
                browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

            try:
                element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + brand_name + "')]")
                print(element.text)
                browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
                time.sleep(10)
                try:
                    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]").click()
                    time.sleep(10)
                    elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("style-list__body.ng-star-inserted")
                    for element in elements:
                        div = element.find_element_by_tag_name("div")
                        colour_code = div.find_element_by_tag_name("span").text
                        code_name, colour_name = colour_code.split(' ',1)
                        colour = colour.upper()
                        if(code_name == color_code):
                            a = 1
                            div = element.find_element_by_class_name("ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid")
                            div = div.find_element_by_class_name("ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-star-inserted")
                            try:
                                pan = div.find_element_by_class_name("warning.ng-star-inserted")
                                flag = 0
                                try:
                                    date = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("warning.ng-star-inserted")
                                    date = date[1].text
                                    if(date == 'SOLD OUT'):
                                        print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ': ' + 'SOLD OUT')
                                        availabilty = 'SOLD OUT'
                                        available_by = ''
                                        flag = 1
                                        present = 'yes'
                                    if(date == 'BACK ORDER'):
                                        print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ': ' + 'BACK ORDER')
                                        availability = 'BACK ORDER'
                                        available_by = ''
                                        flag = 1
                                        present = 'yes'
                                    if(flag == 0):
                                        availability = 'BACK ORDER'
                                        available_by = date
                                        present = 'yes'
                                        print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ',' + date + ':' + ' BACK ORDER')
                                except:
                                    availability = 'BACK ORDER'
                                    available_by = ''
                                    print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ':' + ' BACK ORDER')
                                    present = 'yes'
                            except:
                                availability = 'Available'
                                available_by = ''
                                present = 'yes'
                                print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ':' + ' Available')
                            break
                    if(a == 0):
                        availability = 'Not Available'
                        available_by = ''
                        present = 'no'
                        print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ':' + ' Not Available')
                except:
                    availability = 'Not Available'
                    available_by = ''
                    present = 'no'
                    print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ':' + ' Not Available')
            except:
                present = 'no'
                availability = 'Not Available'
                available_by = ''
                print(brand_name + ',' + name + ',' + color_code + ':' + ' Not Available')
            dict = {
                    'sku': sku_name,
                    'brand': brand_name,
                    'name': name,
                    'clrcode': color_code,
                    'color': colour,
                    'barcode': barcode,
                    'size': size,
                    'present': present,
                    'availability': availability,
                    'available_by': available_by
                    }
            writer.writerow({
                    'sku': sku_name,
                    'brand': brand_name,
                    'name': name,
                    'clrcode': color_code,
                    'color': colour,
                    'barcode': barcode,
                    'size': size,
                    'present': present,
                    'availability': availability,
                    'available_by': available_by
                    })
            a = 0
            var = var + 1
            i = i+1
```

Comment: Can you share your full code so we may reproduce this issue? Also curious, are you set on using python 2.7?

Comment: I have edited my post and shared the code. Please tell can you understand the code? I am running it on pythonanywhere server. This error was not coming on my local server.

Comment: what's the url?

Comment: URL is confidential. I can't share username and password.  Its perfectly working on my local machine. When I click on nav button second time, invalid session Id exception occurs.

Comment: Silly question: Did you open initialize a webdriver element at the first place? Because I believe you've not done it one already. If you have `browser` initialized, then there has to be `browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver")` (or whichever web browser you are using) somewhere in the code.

Comment: Yes I have done it on my code.The code that I have shared is not a complete one. I am using pythonanywhere server. I did a bit of research on my issue. Seems like my session expires very quickly. I have emailed there support team on how to fix this issue and maintain the session for a long time, as this issue does not come on my local server.

Comment: The problem is with maintaining the session of pythoneverywhere server.